# Adding Sass to Django

Tags: python, css, django, web, sass

I want to use SASS in my Django Project. But where should I put all my Sass files ? Should I create a 'Sass' folder in my Project Folder or is it better to create for each App a 'Sass' folder. 
And which converter would you recommend to convert my sass files to css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, sass files are frontend's stuffs so i will put it in `static`.

Comment: But how should I organize these files ? Should I put them in the projects static folder or in the apps static folder and with which tool can I convert the sass files and put them in the correct app/ folder ? I have already tried it with pipeline but with this tool the converted css files are saved in the projects app folder and not in the app/static folder..

Comment: I often put it in project static: `static/appName/resourceType/style.sass`. Once app is removed, just remove `static/appName`.